# add .sh extension to all bash files

Tags: bash, shell-script, xargs

I have a directory containg several files, including those files some are bash scripts but their name doesn't include the .sh extension.
I know I need to use the file command to know the type of files with -type option, I also know that I can redirect the output with xargs so I can rename the files with their origianl name + the .sh extension.
The problem is I don't know how to pipe all the commands together, and how to find files type of only bash ASCII text executable.
Any idea how to do that with a simple command?

Comment: How are you determining which files are bash scripts?

Comment: @NasirRiley This is the main problem actually, idk how to determine only bash script files

Comment: The `file` command is not overly reliable. For example, create a script that starts with twenty comment lines other than `#!/bin/bash`. `file` will categorize it as ASCII text (at least my version of `file` does).

Comment: If you trust `file`, you can generate the list of shell scripts with `file * | grep shell | cut -f1 -d:` (assuming filenames don't contain colons). You step through this list with a `for` loop and rename the files.

Comment: @berndbausch note that the `#!/bin/bash` line must always be the first line; anything not on the first line is ignored (and the kernel will run the script with `/bin/sh`)

Comment: Sure. My point is that you can write scripts without `#!`. They are still shell scripts, but `file` may not recognize them as such.

Comment: I'm curious. Why would you want to rename your scripts to have a `.sh` extension? Compiled programs aren't `.exe` (or even `.out`). Make them executable, add the directory to your path and they can be used just like any other utility

Answer (score 0, accepted):

although that is not fulfilling your homework there is no need for `find` as `grep` kann search directories for files recursively with `-r` (and even that is not needed when file names are passed with globbing)

```
grep -lIw '^#!.*bash' dir/!(*.sh) | xargs -I_ mv _ _.sh
```

---

grep `-r` **dir** will search all files in all subdirectories (not used here)

grep `-l` is similar to `-H` print the file name for each match, but suppress normal output. furthermore it stops after first match similar to `-q` or `-m1`

grep `-I` exclude binary files, process text files only

grep `-w` **bash** will match whole word only (won't match **bash**ed)

---

regex `^` **#!** match begin of line only (won't match #**#!**)

regex `.` match any byte `*` any occurrence = `.*` any string

---

pathname expansion (globbing) `*.sh` matches pattern file.sh

extended globbing `!(pattern)` matches anything except pattern

ls `dir/!(*.sh)` list all files in **dir** excluding **dir/file.sh** files

---

xargs `-I` **pattern** will insert arguments on each position **pattern** is used `_` in this example:

```
mv   _     _  .sh
mv file1 file1.sh
mv file2 file2.sh
```

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep https://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-extended-globbing

Comment: This will match files with `#!` at the start of *any* line.

Comment: ... will also match *'#!/bin/sh # this is not a bash script'* or *'#! like fruits of calabash tree'* but prefer regex *kiss* for demonstration. focus was more on avoiding *'script.sh.sh.sh'* on multiple runs

Answer (score 2):

If you've set up any of the standard shebang lines it looks like `file` (at least version 5.39) should be able to detect them:

```
$ echo '#!/usr/bin/env bash' > 1
$ echo '#!/bin/bash' > 2
$ echo '#!/usr/bin/bash' > 3
$ file *
1: Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable
2: Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable
3: Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable
```

So we should be able to do this:

```bsh
for path in ./*
do
    if [[ "$(file "$path")" = "${path}: Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable" ]]
    then
        mv "$path" "${path}.bash"
    fi
done
```

This works for the above example files (and should work for unusual filenames, including those containing space characters, starting with a hyphen, or ending with a newline):

```
$ ls
1.bash  2.bash  3.bash
```

This will probably *not* work if your files do not have shebang lines (which is reasonable for files which are [sourced by other scripts](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Sourcing) or the shebang lines are wrong (such as [`#!/bin/sh`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10376206/96588)).

(I've used ".bash" since that is more explicit than ".sh".)

Comment: Be careful. I just wrote a tiny script with accented characters, and I get told `/tmp/xxx: Bourne-Again shell script, UTF-8 Unicode text executable`. The file is *not* executable, by the way (Fedora 33, UTF-8).

Comment: @vonbrand `file` is fallible for sure - after all, it's a heuristic. I suspect "executable" here is probably meant in the "it's something you can run" sense rather than "it's a file with the executable flag set." Which is unfortunate but not *technically* wrong.

Comment: @alecxs You might want to post that as a separate answer with a bit of context.

Comment: what I'm concerned about is that the pattern you are looking for is *not* correct.

Comment: @vonbrand The actual output of `file` is irrelevant here, the important thing is that it accurately identifies *Bash scripts.*